# Django: Create and save a model using JSON data

Tags: json, django, django-models

Im building an app using Django 1.10 as backend and Angular 2 4.0 for frontend.

Is it possible to create and save a model instance from a JSON data object?

Example: This model:

```
class PartOne(models.Model):
  gender = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=[(1, "Male"), (2, "Female")])
  gender_na = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  height = models.SmallIntegerField()
  height_na = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

JSON:

```
json = {
'gender': 1,
'gender_na':False,
'height':195,
'height_na':False
}
```

I **dont** want to manually create the model:

`PartOne.objects.create(gender=json['gender'], gender_na=json['gender_na'], height=json['height'], height_na=json['height_na]`

Im looking for an automated solution, like this:

`PartOne.objects.create_from_json(json)`

Comment: You should investigate django-rest-framework and its serializers functionality, which is meant exactly for this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could just do,

```
PartOne.objects.create(**json)
```

You can use the **kwargs syntax when calling functions by constructing a dictionary of keyword arguments and passing it to your function.

This is documented on [section 4.7.4 of python tutorial.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), under unpacking argument lists.

Also, note that the same dict is not passed into the function. A new copy is created, so "json" is not kwargs.

Comment: Is there a way to the same but given a list of json objects instead of a single one?

Comment: `[f(**item) for item in json_list]`, maybe?

Comment: @zaidfazil you can iterate over the Json and save individualy. `for this_json in json:
    PartOne.objects.create(**this_json )`

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to take a look at [`modelform_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function) if you want to run more validation on your data or have more control over input. You can also do good stuff like attaching files.

```
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory

form = modelform_factory(PartOne, fields=('gender', 'gender_na', 'height', 'height_na',))
populated_form = form(data=my_json)

if populated_form.is_valid():
    populated_form.save()
else:
    # do something, maybe with populated_form.errors
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way I use, create a method in the model (serialize) and then use JsonResponse to return:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    u_username = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    p_pic = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    p_comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    def serializeProfile(self):
        return {
            "pk": self.pk,
            "username": self.username,
            "email": self.email
        }
```

And then call the function, inside of the jsonRespone:

```
u_profile = User.objects.get(username='username')
JsonResponse(u_profile.serializeProfile())
```

The above worked for me.