# How to speed up djangorestframework-bulk inserts?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am using djangorestframework 3.9.2, and djangorestframework-bulk 0.2.1.  I am trying to insert 100 objects via a REST POST, and it's submitting way too many queries.  Details below.

The model object:

```
class TheObj(models.Model):
    fk1 = models.ForeignKey(Foreign1, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=False)
    fk2 = models.ForeignKey(Foreign2, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=False)
    data = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    # more data here ..
```

The serializer and viewset:

```
class TheObjSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer,
                       BulkSerializerMixin,
                       BulkCreateModelMixin):
    class Meta:
        model = TheObj
        fields = '__all__'
        list_serializer_class = BulkListSerializer

    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        queryset = queryset.select_related('fk1')
        return queryset.select_related('fk2')

class TheObjResultViewSet(BulkModelViewSet):
    queryset = TheObj.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TheObjSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = TheObj.objects.all()
        # Set up eager loading to avoid N+1 selects
        return self.get_serializer_class().setup_eager_loading(queryset)
```

If I insert 100 objects via a bulk REST call (REST call where data is an array of 100 objects), it issues 4 calls per object:

1. RelatedField.run_validation (fk1)
2. RelatedField.run_validation (fk2)
3. qs_exists validators.py (TheObj)
4. insert (TheObj)

But queries 1-3 are not very useful, because they'll already be checked by the database.  1 and 2 have foreign key constraints, 3 has a uniqueness constraint.

Well, 1 and 2 need to be run at least once, but if they share fk objects, the results should be cached if I use prefetching, but they don't seem to be.

So my two detailed questions:

1. How do I get djangorestframework to not issue useless queries #1-3?
2. How do I get djangorestframework-bulk to issue one insert instead of 100 inserts?

Doing one bulk insert is 0.2 seconds.  The current speed is about 30 seconds.  It's brutal.

I've read [this](https://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/) and prefetching doesn't seem to help (the setup_eager_loading above).

I've tried not using setup_eager_loading.  I've tried not using BulkSerializerMixin, or BulkCreateModelMixin, or BulkListSerializer.

I've tried a number of combinations of things.

Perhaps I need to set up my foreign keys differently in the serializer?

For #2, do I have to get many=True in there somewhere?

Thoughts welcome.

**EDIT**: I was able to remove one of the queries (the unique_together validation) by adding this to the TheObjSerializer:

```
def run_validators(self, value):
    """For speed, don't run serializer validation.  Let the DB validate."""
    pass
```

The foreign-key lookups seem more needed, but I'm having trouble with prefetching and caching.

Comment: Well if you don't want to run any validation and just enter the raw data straight into the DB and let it do the validation for you then you can as well just eliminate the serializer and create the objects with the JSON input you get in the view

Comment: Seems like a good idea. I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44022458/34935. However, the foreign-key lookups look required to make model objects that have other model objects as fields .. even though it's just going to turn that model object back into an id (that was passed in with the original data)! This is complicated.

Comment: Of course. How else will it ensure that the id you provided is valid and has an object it points to? It cannot add an id for a non-existing object so it has to validate that the object in fact exists

Comment: Yep. That's exactly what I want it to not do. I have the id, I just got it, I know it's there, I don't want it to re-verify. I just want it to bulk insert as fast as it can. I could hand-write the code completely independent of djangorestframework-bulk, but I thought there might be a way to tweak it.